Angular Elements Overwrites Multiple Instances on the Same Page
I'm using Angular Elements within a WordPress site to show the same component with different attributes on the same page. While the components render correctly when placed on different pages, they fail to render properly when I attempt to use multiple instances on the same page.
<app-test type='1'></app-test>
<app-test type='2'></app-test>

This is my current main.ts for bootstrapping the Angular application, which works when the components are on separate pages but not when they are together:
if(document.querySelector('app-test')) {
  bootstrapApplication(TestComponent).catch(err => console.error(err));
}

For solution i tried to make it uniquely render component with different types but it still doesnt work. It overwrites same component with different attribute data. I can solve this with changing the component structure a little bit, but i really want to know what i'm missing here.
  document.querySelectorAll('app-test').forEach((el) => {
    const typeAttr = el.getAttribute('type') || 'default';

    bootstrapApplication(TestComponent, {
      providers: [{ provide: TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, useValue: typeAttr }]
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
  });

I tried to change custom HTML elements used in WP and tried to select them on main.ts but didn't work.

You can only bootstrap once is my understanding.
SO you can add the bootstrap application in the HTML element, which is at the root of both the tags on the same page (for eg, bootstrap it on the body tag of the HTML). Would suggest you use a different way to use the selector.
@Component({
  selector: '.app-root',
  ...
  `,
})
export class App {
  ...
}
bootstrapApplication(App)

So your HTML will look like, here the app-test is a standalone component added to the imports array of App component.
...
<body class="app-root">
    <app-test [type]='1'></app-test>
    <app-test [type]='2'></app-test>
</body>
...

